# Python - Scrapy - Navigating through a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, navigation

I’m trying to use Scrapy to log into a website, then navigate within than website, and eventually download data from it. Currently I’m stuck in the middle of the navigation part. Here are the things I looked into to solve the problem on my own.

1. Datacamp course on Scrapy
2. *[Following Pagination Links with Scrapy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9Nni6G-iOc)*
3. http://scrapingauthority.com/2016/11/22/scrapy-login/
4. *[Scrapy - Following Links](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_following_links.htm)*
5. *[Relative URL to absolute URL Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085893/relative-url-to-absolute-url-scrapy)*

However, I do not seem to connect the dots.

Below is the code I currently use. I manage to log in (when I call the "open_in_browser" function, I see that I’m logged in). I also manage to "click" on the first button on the website in the "parse2" part (if I call "open_in_browser" after parse 2, I see that the navigation bar at the top of the website has gone one level deeper.

The main problem is now in the "parse3" part as I cannot navigate another level deeper (or maybe I can, but the "open_in_browser" does not open the website any more - only if I put it after parse or parse 2). My understanding is that I put multiple "parse-functions" after another to navigate through the website.

Datacamp says I always need to start with a "start request function" which is what I tried but within the YouTube videos, etc. I saw evidence that most start directly with parse functions. Using "inspect" on the website for parse 3, I see that this time href is a relative link and I used different methods (See source 5) to navigate to it as I thought this might be the source of error.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class LoginNeedScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "login"
    start_urls = ["<some website>"]

    def parse(self, response):
        loginTicket = response.xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input[1]/@value').extract_first()
        execution = response.xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input[2]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
                                                   'loginTicket': loginTicket,
                                                   'execution': execution,
                                                   'username': '<someusername>',
                                                   'password': '<somepassword>'},
                                         callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self, response):
        next_page_url = response.xpath('/html/body/nav/div[2]/ul/li/a/@href').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse3)

    def parse3(self, response):
        next_page_url_2 = response.xpath('/html//div[@class = "headerPanel"]/div[3]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url_2)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url, callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(LoginNeedScraper)
process.start()
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? You can use `self.logger.debug()` to log messages there, you could log the content of `absolute_url`, see if it contains the expected URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [rules](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) in order to scrape a website completely. Let's say you want to crawl all links in the header of the website and then open that link in order to see the main page to which that link was referring.

In order to achieve this, firstly identify what you need to scrape and mark CSS or XPath selectors for those links and put them in a rule. Every rule has a default callback to `parse` or you can also assign it to some other method. I am attaching a dummy example of creating rules, and you can map it accordingly to your case:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=[crawl_css_selectors])),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=[product_css_selectors]), callback='parse_item')
)
```