# How to modify links in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I made a scrapy crawler that extracts all links from a website and adds them to a list. My problem is that it only gives me the href attribute which isn't the full link. I already tried adding the base url to the links, but that doesn't always work because not all links are at the same level of directory in the website tree. I would like to yield the full link. For example:

`[index.html, ../contact-us/index.html, ../../../book1/index.html]`

I would like to be able to yield this:

```
[example.com/index.html, example.com/contact-us/index.html, example.com/adventure/books/book1/index.html]
```

My crawler's code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

links_list = set([])

class LinkCrawler(CrawlSpider):

   name = "Crawler"
   rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_links', follow=True)]

   def parse_links(self, response):
       href = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
       links_list.add(response.url)

       for link in href:
           if '../' in link:
               link = link.replace('../', '')
               links_list.add(link)

       for link in links_list:
           if ' ' in link:
               link_w_space = link.replace(' ', '%20')
               links_list.add(link_w_space)
               links_list.remove(link)


print(links_list)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative URL to absolute URL Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085893/relative-url-to-absolute-url-scrapy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the urljoin function from urllib:  it converts the relative url into one with an absolute path.

`from urllib.parse import urljoin`

`new_url = urljoin(base_url, relative_url)`

As pointed out in this post:
[Relative URL to absolute URL Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085893/relative-url-to-absolute-url-scrapy)

Comment: Unfortunately, the urljoin method isn't useful in this case because it will simply join the urls together. This is a problem because as I mentioned in the question, not all links are at the same level on the website tree(not all links are from the first page.)